# Is there a way to check the number of CPU threads in use with sycl?

Tags: sycl, dpc++

I'm not sure this question is correctly formulated, I'm still learning.
I was wondering if there is a way, when I run a sycl program with a `cpu_selector` to get if I'm using it as single core or multi core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of possible using `sycl::info::device::max_compute_units`. Here's a minimal example:

```cpp
#include <CL/sycl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  sycl::device d = sycl::cpu_selector().select_device();
  std::cout << d.get_info<sycl::info::device::max_compute_units>() << std::endl;
}
```

On my machine (which has 8 physical cores & 16 hardware threads), this returns `16`.

I think it is generally true that OpenCL considers hardware threads to be 'compute units', but I can't confirm this. Furthermore, it'll only tell you how many hardware threads the OpenCL backend considers are *present*, not how many you are *using*.

**Edit for follow up question:**

I think the OpenCL backend will always use all available resources. However, if you're working on a CPU, you can limit available threads using [`taskset`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html). For example, if I set the mask to use only thread 0:

```
taskset 0x00000001 ./a.out
```

I get the answer `1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So if I'm benchmarking some sycl code to compare the performances on CPU vs GPU vs iGPU there's no way to know how many CPU threads I'm using (or even choosing how many up to hardware_concurrency) ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to answer this. Perhaps you could add this to your original question so my answer makes more sense?